# Linq Expressions -> Build a Where(...).Single(...) Linq Tree Expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I'm trying to build an `Expression<Func<TEntity, TKey>>` like:

```
e.Collection.Where(c => c.Key.Equals("key")).Single()
```

So, up to now, I've been able to build something like that. However, I'm not quite to figure out how to build `Where().Single()` chain:

```
Type entityType = typeof(TElementType);
PropertyInfo collectionPropertyInfo = entityType.GetProperty("Metainfos"); // TODO: Pick the property up instead of using a literal string
if (collectionPropertyInfo == null)
    throw new MissingFieldException(string.Format("{0} collection doesn't appear in {1}", "MetaInfos", entityType));

Type collGenericType = collectionPropertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
if (!collGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Domain.MetaInfoValue)))
    throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format("Collection generic type doesn't inherit from {1}", collGenericType));

ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "t");
ParameterExpression metaInfoParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(collGenericType, "m");

MemberExpression collectionMemberExpression = Expression.Property(entityParameter, collectionPropertyInfo);
MethodInfo whereMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Where") && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).First().MakeGenericMethod(collGenericType);
MethodInfo singleMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Single") && m.GetParameters().Length == 1).First().MakeGenericMethod(collGenericType);

LambdaExpression innerCondition = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.GetDelegateType(collGenericType, typeof(bool)),
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Property(metaInfoParameterExpression, "Key"),
        Expression.Constant(field)
    ),
    metaInfoParameterExpression
);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, TKeyType>>(
    Expression.Call(
        singleMethod,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, bool>>(
            Expression.Call(whereMethod, collectionMemberExpression, innerCondition), 
            entityParameter
        )
    )
);}
```

It throws me an `ArgumentException`:

> It's not allowed to use an expression of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Backend.Domain.MetaInfoValue]</code> for the returned value`System.Boolean`

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `Expression.Call` for `Single` is the problem. You need to provide (1) the `source` and (2) the `arguments`.  Right now, you seem to be trying to provide both of them as the same argument (`Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, bool>>(Expression.Call(whereMethod, collectionMemberExpression, innerCondition), entityParameter);`).

Think what a `Single` expression usually looks like: `myEnumerable.Single(o => o.Key == iKey);`. See how your `Source` (`myEnumerable`) is different than your selection expression (`o => o.Key == iKey`)?

If you create two expressions as arguments for your `Single` call (one `source` with `Enumerable` input and output, and one selector (`Expression.Lambda<Func<TElementType, bool>>`), it should solve the issue.